# Change value in specific row in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, rename

I need some help in python. I need to modify the value in a specific row. I have something like this.

```
ID      Status      Customer Name 
345      New         Braskem S.A
923     Closed       Braskem 
046      New         Braskem S.A
195      New         Braskem S.A
537     In Progress  Braskem 
237     On Hold      Vale
355     Closed       BIMBO
```

Here i need to change all the customer name "Braskem S.A" to "Braskem" 
Can someone give me a hand with this please? Thanks I will appreciate the help and sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this. Arguably the simplest is to use `pandas.DataFrame.replace`:

```
df.replace(to_replace='Braskem S.A', value='Braskem')
```

You can also use a boolean mask or a map.